# How do I get this page to redirect? (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

when I go to https://www.safepub.com it redirects to https://www.safepub.com/home. How do I get that to stop? I found this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.safepub.com/$1 [R,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.safepub.com/home [r=301,nc,L]

   RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/store/(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^/store/(.*)$ https://www.safepub.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

I'm not very familiar with that language, so I'm not sure what it's saying. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.safepub.com/home [r=301,nc,L]
```

In Above lines `RewriteCond` check if there is no string after `/` then it will redirect REQUEST_URI to `https://www.safepub.com/home`.
Flag `R` (default R=301) takes you to redirected url. If you don't want to rewrite your url to `/home` then remove flag `R`.